# How to scrape dynamic table data (world bank website)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, scrapy, webdriverwait

I was just trying to scrape the results framework information for several projects on the world bank's site. The library that I am using is scrapy but am open to even using selenium.

Link: (https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P153012)

The problem that I am facing is:

1. The tables are dynamically generated and for some projects they would be completely missing or have lesser fields (this ensures I can't use scrapy as I don't know how to deal with javascript using scrapy)
2. With selenium the code I am using is as follows, but this only allows me to extract all the text and not individual cell items (can the same be done or am i just trying to do a fool's errand):

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P153012"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/Users/thenewcomputer/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
tables = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ng-tns-c7-3")
for table in tables:
    title = table.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li/table')
title
for x in title:
    print(x.text) #because i wanted to figure out if this was working correctly
```

Do let me know if there is an easier way of doing this and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To print the texts from the tables, as an example from the table with heading ***Results Framework*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P153012")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[starts-with(., 'Results Framework')]//following::div[1]//ul//table"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Increase of Municipality of Fortaleza own-source revenue capacity through planning and land-value capture instruments Value 0 - 17.75% increase in property tax revenues- 546.2% increase in PMF's revenues through Fortaleza online- 171.90% increase inSEUMA's revenues collected from use of urban instruments - 20% increase in property tax revenues- 100% increase in PMF's revenues through Fortaleza Online- 115% increase in SEUMA'srevenues collected from use of urban instruments
  Date August 1, 2016 April 28, 2021 June 30, 2023
  ```

Comment

Comment: Hi thanks, this helped a lot for the other tables but for the results framework table (the last table in the page), I can't find the h3 tag. Also given that this is a print output is there a way to seperate each cell's output as one output or would that only be possible with regex

Comment: @Anikan Can you raise a new question for your new requirement please?

Comment: Hi Debanjan but the original query was also about just the information in "the results framework information". But thanks for all your help

Comment: @Anikan Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.